# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am trying to use JPA in my Play app and when I try to load my app I receive a PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit

These are my settings: 
**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   ....
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.28",
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final"
)
```

**conf/META-INF/persistance.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testDB"
db.default.user="root"
db.default.password="root"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

Can please someone tell me what I am doing wrong... 
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your information above are correct, I assume a filename typo: rename `conf/META-INF/persistance.xml` to `conf/META-INF/persistence.xml`.